# Can I override values in ansible.cfg from the cli?

Tags: ansible

I'd like to override:

```
[defaults]
roles_path = ansible_galaxy:roles
```

from outside of `ansible.cfg` if possible. Is there some way of achieving that without creating a separate `ansible.cfg`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no general method for overriding settings from Ansible configuration file.

For the use case you want, you can use `ANSIBLE_ROLES_PATH` environment variable:

```
ANSIBLE_ROLES_PATH=/path/to/roles ansible-playbook my_playbook.yml
```